# Displaying Tags via the console with "Log To Console"

Tags: robotframework

I'm attempting to take the defined `test.robot` file content of `[Tags]` and display it on the Console. Here's what I have:

```
[Tags]  cat  dog
```

Now, I'm wondering how to have `Log To Console` output the tags?

I have, thus far, tried the following:

```
    ${TagVariable}=    Tags
    ${TagVariable1}=    Tags[0]
    ${TagVariable2}=    Tags[1]
    ${TagVariable3}=    [Tags]
    ${TagVariable4}=    [Tags][0]
    ${TagVariable5}=    [Tags][1]
    Log To Console  Tags
    Log To Console  [Tags]
    Log To Console  [Tags][0]
    Log To Console  [Tags][1]
    Log To Console  ${TagVariable}
    Log To Console  ${TagVariable1}
    Log To Console  ${TagVariable2}
    Log To Console  ${TagVariable3}
    Log To Console  ${TagVariable4}
    Log To Console  ${TagVariable5}
```

I just can't seem to grasp it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Robot Provides several automatic variables. [You can find all of them here](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#automatic-variables)

The one that you need is this one

- `@{TEST TAGS}` : Contains the tags of the current test case in alphabetical order. Can be modified dynamically using Set Tags and Remove Tags keywords.

You may need to print it as `\n@{TEST TAGS}`, in the `.robot` file, depending on your context.

Comment: hmm. 
`Log To Console   @{TEST TAGS}` 
Does not seem to show anything. What might I be doing wrong on this one? Also, thanks for the link!

Comment: What is the error message? Probably the log to console keyword is expecting a string and not a list Could you try this? Log to console    ${TEST TAGS} .  If it does not work please post the error message and I may be able to help you more

Comment: There is no error message. I got it to display correctly when I added \n before the `@{TEST TAGS}` and also \n before the `${TEST TAGS}`.  Then it would work.